# python not recognize webdriver firefox&chrome

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

i use python 3.6.4 and install selenium with pip command

> pip install -U selenium
>   when i use a simple code like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

i get error:

```
from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
ImportError: No module named 'selenium.firefox'
```

i download chromedriver.exe and add this path to system environment
bot not working
how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using `from selenium import webdriver` and not `from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver`?

Comment: yes i sure,it only define from selenium import webdriver

Comment: I can't reproduce your error using `from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: If you downloaded `chromedriver.exe`, why aren't you using `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`?

Comment: Make sure that you are running and installing on the same version of python. Try `pip3 install selenium` or `python3 -m pip install selenium`.

Comment: i install 2 python 3.6.4 and 3.4.3 i think Interference environment reason of this error after delete all pythons and clean directory,registery,environment  and install only python 3.4.3 this problem fixed